# unable to connect MYSQL using PHP "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect php and mysql.

Here is the **code :**

```
<?php

$response=array();
require_once 'C:\wamp\www\android_connect\db_connect.php';
$db=new DB_CONNECT();


$result=mysql_query("select * from product")or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $response["products"]=array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $product=array();
        $product["pid"]=$row["pid"];
        $product["name"]=$row["name"];
        $product["price"]=$row["price"];
        $product["description"]=$row["description"];

        array_push($response["products"],$product);
    }
    $response["success"]=1;
}
else
{
    $response["success"]=0;
    $response["message"]="No products found";
}
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

When i am trying to open the file using `WAMP` installed on my computer it throws the following **error :**

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\get_all_products.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\get_all_products.php on line 8
```

In my case **line 8** is:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from product")or die(mysql_error());
```

and the **code** of `db_connect` is as follows:

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT
{

    function _construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function _destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect()
    {
        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','kamani') or die (mysql_error());
        $db=mysql_select_db('mobileinventory') or die (mysql_error());
        return $con;
    }

    function close()
    {
        mysql_close();
    }
}

?>
```

To complete see the error here i am uploading its snap.
[image]

I am **unable to solve** this **error**.

Comment: check by removing the password.enter empty password.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add two underscores for magic methods:

```
function __construct() {
  $this->connect();
}
```

Elsewhere the constructor and so the connect method will never be called. Same to __destruct() method.

**And you should not use the mysql extension of PHP because it's deprecated and gets removed in one of the next releases of PHP. Use PDO or mysqli instead.**

Comment: can you tell me something more about PDO and mysqli and my main purpose is i am developing android app.

Comment: Not related to Android, they are PHP libraries to connect MySQL database server.

Comment: See here: http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php and here http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

you have to do

```
$db=new DB_CONNECT();
$db->connect();
```

it seems that you are not connected to the database, or fix @TiMESPLiNTER suggestion

Comment: connect is called in constructor in database file

Comment: the contractor is not called because it is missing underscore _

Answer (score 1):

in database file you have to change you constructor (and destructor) as well to

```
 function __construct()
 {
    $this->connect();
}

function __destruct()
{
    $this->close();
}
```